# JSON Serialize and Deserialize with List<string> not working

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, jsonconvert

i have the following problem on my development:

i want to serialize and save a List of strings (System.List) on my iPhone. The List contains Errormessages which occurs by the running application. 
Then i want to Load it back and Deserialize it to save the list in my Application. This happens with the following code (Code shortened, unnessesary parts cut off):

```
List<string> MyList = {"Message One", "Message two"};

//Serialize 
string Temp = Newtonsoft.Json.Jsonconvert.SerializeObject(MyList);

//Save Data
using (Streamwriter sw = File.AppendText(Path))
{
     sw.WriteLine(Temp);
}

//Load Data
MyList = Newtonsoft.Json.Jsonconvert.Deserialize<List<string>>(File.ReadAllText(Path));
```

And then i get the exception 
`` "Error converting value "one" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'." ``

Output on the iOS System is in a .txt file:

`["One","Two"]`

What's the problem?

Comment: Using `File.AppendText` is almost certainly going to cause problems. You can't append one JSON document (or similar) to another. I suspect the problem is that your file starts with a `"one"` on a line on its own, and that *isn't* the start of a list.

Comment: Check whether `File.ReadAllText(Path)` gets you the data you have sent.

Comment: It would be great if you could show compilable code, than shortened ones like above.

Comment: [It's working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFkTjv) ... as other wrote your file [not contains valid JSON](https://dotnetfiddle.net/daoWWk)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is on: File.AppendText("C:\temp\t.txt")

it will append new lines on every run. after 1 run. you cannot convert All file content.

```cs
            List<string> MyList = new List<string>{ "One", "two" };

            //Serialize 
            string Temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyList);

//Do this.
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\temp\\t.txt",Temp);

            //Comment this.
            //using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("C:\\temp\\t.txt"))
            //{
            //    sw.WriteLine(Temp);
            //}

            //Load Data
            MyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(File.ReadAllText("C:\\temp\\t.txt"));
```

Comment: Installed is Newtonsoft.Json (12.0.2)

Comment: @IngmarWeix i think your exception reason of File.AppendText("C:\\temp\\t.txt")) it always append new lines to file. You cannot convert it anymore after 1. test :)

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! I've update the JSON Files and correct the mistake of deserializing. I deserialized to List<List<string>> instead of List<string>..

Comment: yes, you can. But first time you will have only List not List of List. Append cause of this. And I found mistake. So Am I deserve an Accept ? :)

Comment: @IngmarWeix wont you ACCEPT my answer ?